# Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' in sitecore 10.3 XM in Sitecore 10.3

Tags: sxa

I am having issue in IFrame. IFrame cross domain url is not working in sitecore 10.3 XM.

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

I have also added below header.

```
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="allowAll" />
```

Comment: Can you please paste url you are trying to embed via IFrame?

Answer (score 1):

The header `X-Frame-Options` should be set in the response of the URL that you are trying to embed rather than its parent page. If I understood correctly, in your scenario, it is a URL from the domain `https://www.google.com/`. You can find more details about this HTTP header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

Please make sure that you are using the correct URL for your iframe, because it looks like the owner of this URL does not allow it to be embedded on external websites.